# Somar dados da tabela "pivot" de relação many to many

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Possuo 3 tabelas `(clientes,seguradoras e clientes_seguradoras)` que se relacionam através de 2 Models `(Cliente e Seguradora)` no Laravel

Cada cliente pode ter várias seguradoras, e pra cada seguradora ele pode adicionar o seu preço.

As tabelas seguem a seguinte estrutura:

```
clientes:
- nome,
- sobrenome
.....

seguradoras:
- nome,
- imagem
.....

clientes_seguradoras:
- cliente_id,
- seguradora_id,
- preco <-- valor que quero somar
.....
```

A relação entre cliente e seguradora é feita da seguinte forma no model `Cliente`:

```
public function seguradoras()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Seguradora', 'clientes_seguradoras', 'cliente_id', 'seguradora_id')
            ->withPivot(['preco']);
    }
```

Uso o model `Cliente` junto das seguradoras da seguinte forma num `Controller` responsável por efetuar buscas:

```
$clientes = Cliente::with(['seguradoras'])
// .... algumas condições where() em cima do cliente
    ->paginate(50);
```

Porém só consigo efetuar a soma fazendo um foreach "na mão" dentro da própria view com os dados do `paginate(50)`, só que o `paginate` é limitado aos resultados exibidos na página e não ao resultado total da busca (query do model), e retornar todos os resultados de uma só vez e fazer um foreach não é eficiente e consome muita memória, pois são milhares

Como posso fazer uma query para somar o preço total da tabela pivot mantendo qualquer "where" que eu faço em cima do Model cliente?

Comment: você quer que saia qual resultado? (por exemplo linha) seria melhor ai um join com groupby ...

Comment: Eu queria o float da soma, eu resolvi com um join e group by em cima do model Cliente, mas queria saber se existe alguma solução mais "elegante" com o Eloquent

Comment: como você fez? se pode criar scope etc ... mas, cara o Builder é igual e um puxadinho do Eloquent

Answer (score 0):

No Laravel 7 ou anterior não existe uma forma simplificada do framework para fazer essa consulta, mas usando o Eloquent é possível fazer da seguinte forma:

```
class Cliente extends Model
{
  public function seguradoras()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Seguradora::class, 'clientes_seguradoras', 'cliente_id', 'seguradora_id');
    // removi o with ->withPivot()
  }
}

Cliente::with(['seguradoras' => function ($query) {
  $query->selectRaw('sum(`clientes_seguradoras`.`preco`) as sum_preco')
    ->groupBy('clientes_seguradoras.cliente_id')
    ->groupBy('clientes_seguradoras.seguradora_id');
}])->get();
```

No Laravel 8 foi incluído um método [`withSum`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) e pelo que entendi da documentação a consulta ficaria:

```
Cliente::with(['seguradoras' => function ($query) {
  $query->withSum('pivot', 'preco'); // talvez precise dos group by
}])->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

É laravel?

Se sim, tu não precisa sofrer muito para isso na sua model tu vai criar o seguinte atributo:

```
protected $appends = [ 'soma_total' ];
```

Ainda na sua model tu vai criar a seguinte função:

```
public function getSomaTotalAttribute(): string
{
    // aqui tu faz sua mágica utilizando o objecto $this
}
```

Ai quando tu fizer qualquer query seja pivot, get, has many, has one automaticamente voltará um **attribute soma_total**.

Atenção: só faça isso também se o caso esse atributo para si seja de alguma forma extremamente necessário como a model no todo, caso, tu só precise ter essa soma em especificos momentos é mais lhe aconselhável faze-la numa repository.